# Locate laptop using geolocation

Tags: java, jquery, html, geolocation

Hey im looking for some advice, im working on a project to create website that is able to track and locate a users laptop based on geolocation, in a very basic idea to what 'prey' does. So far, i've got my site which when accessed shows on a google map where I am, but the problem is that the code used for the location runs from within the html code of the site, which means it can only show you where basically the machine that runs the code from is and not where your laptop is, which isnt very useful. What I need to do is to have this code run from a persons laptop so that it updates its location onto the website intermittingly, so that in the event of the laptop being stolen all a user needs to do is log into the website and they can see where there machine is. Im just looking for advice or guidance on this as I cant seem to find a whole lot out on the net thanks

Comment: "Im just looking for advice or guidance on this as I cant seem to find a whole lot out on the net thanks" - seeing how all over the place your question is, it seems you need to think about decomposing your problem more. What's the *one specific* thing you're stuck on right now? ("How do I start with all of the above" is not a good answer.)

Comment: This is way beyond the scope of the stack overflow forum.

Comment: *"log into the website and they can see where there machine.."*  **..was** - the moment before the thief removed the battery.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this won't really be possible unless the user has some background process running on the laptop. Similar to the way that [find my iphone](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8) works, the device is always running a program in the background.

This will not be possible with just html and javascript alone

Comment: I was expecting thats what I will need to do, so that it runs from the users machine, but how do I get this to run and update the machines location on the website end, is it possible using a script that runs on the laptop to acquire the laptops location, and then have it send the co-ordinates to the website?

Comment: Nope, not at all. What if the *thief* doesn't access your website. How will your script be able to run then?